# How to parse particular line of text from Jenkins Console output into a csv file

Tags: shell, parsing, jenkins

I have the several of following lines in Jenkins console output. I wanted to store them in a csv file in 2 columns.

Follwoing is the text line:

```
NumberOfTestCases in https://****:****@bess-bitbucket.bearingpoint.com/scm/bnktst/stat-de-gui-testcases.git are 1
NumberOfTestCases in https://****:****@bess-bitbucket.bearingpoint.com/scm/bnktst/stat-nl-gui-testcases.git are 91
NumberOfTestCases in https://****:****@bess-bitbucket.bearingpoint.com/scm/bnktst/loan-gui-testcases.git are 1
NumberOfTestCases in https://****:****@bess-bitbucket.bearingpoint.com/scm/bnktst/liq-gui-testcases.git are 37
NumberOfTestCases in https://****:****@bess-bitbucket.bearingpoint.com/scm/bnktst/finrep-gui-testcases.git are 3
```

Expected csv format:

| Repo_URL | Number_Of_Testfiles |
| --- | --- |
| https://****:****@bess-bitbucket.bearingpoint.com/scm/bnktst/stat-nl-gui-testcases.git | 91 |
| https://****:****@bess-bitbucket.bearingpoint.com/scm/bnktst/finrep-gui-testcases.git | 3 |
| https://****:****@bess-bitbucket.bearingpoint.com/scm/bnktst/liq-gui-testcases.git | 37 |
| https://****:****@bess-bitbucket.bearingpoint.com/scm/bnktst/loan-gui-testcases.git | 1 |
| https://****:****@bess-bitbucket.bearingpoint.com/scm/bnktst/stat-de-gui-testcases.git | 1 |

I am able to save total console output into csv file already, but i want only the baove mentioned part.

```
wget ${BUILD_URL}/consoleText -O ${WORKSPACE}/SomeFile.csv
```

Comment: Something like `{ echo "Repo_URL,Number_Of_Testfiles"; wget ${BUILD_URL}/consoleText | sed -n 's/.*\(https.*git\)\ are\ \([[:digit:]]\{1,\}\)/\1,\2/p'; } > SomeFile.csv`? This works for your example data but it's hard to say without more example input data and the expected output

Comment: @jared_mamrot : the above script s generating a empty csv with only headers. I will update the question with more input data lines.

Comment: @jared_mamrot it is bash only

Comment: Is doing this as a Post script in Jenkins an option?

Comment: @ycr yes it is an option.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution for you. This is a bit tightly coupled to your output pattern. So make sure you tweak the code accordingly. If you need a more robust way try using `Pattern Matching` instead of relying on string splits.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
     stage("Output") {
                steps{
                    script {
                        
                        echo "Something else...................."
                        echo "Something else...................."
                        echo "Something else...................."
                        echo "Something else...................."
                        echo "NumberOfTestCases in https://****:****@bess-bitbucket.bearingpoint.com/scm/bnktst/stat-de-gui-testcases.git are 1"
                        echo "NumberOfTestCases in https://****:****@bess-bitbucket.bearingpoint.com/scm/bnktst/stat-nl-gui-testcases.git are 91"
                        echo "NumberOfTestCases in https://****:****@bess-bitbucket.bearingpoint.com/scm/bnktst/loan-gui-testcases.git are 1"
                        echo "NumberOfTestCases in https://****:****@bess-bitbucket.bearingpoint.com/scm/bnktst/liq-gui-testcases.git are 37"
                        echo "NumberOfTestCases in https://****:****@bess-bitbucket.bearingpoint.com/scm/bnktst/finrep-gui-testcases.git are 3"
                        echo "Something else...................."
                        echo "Something else...................."
                        echo "Something else...................."
                        }
                }
            }
    }
    post {
        success {
            echo 'The process is successfully Completed....'
            script {
                def log = currentBuild.rawBuild.getLog().split('\n')
                // Writing the title row
                sh "echo 'Repo_URL,Number_Of_Testfiles' >> file.csv"
                for(def line : log) {
                    if(line.contains("NumberOfTestCases in")){
                        def parts = line.split(" ")
                        def csvLine = parts[2].replaceAll("\\*","") + "," + parts[4]
                        sh "echo $csvLine >> file.csv"
                    }
                }
                sh "cat file.csv"
            }
        }
    }
}
```